# Baking Shaders For Unity

Tags: shaders

I’m still fairly new to Blender, but I have a simple model with some shaders that I want to bake onto it, but I’m finding difficulty baking it properly. For one, it seems to be baking the current lighting onto it, is there a way to set it to not bake the lighting settings?

Also, upon importing it into my game, it has a weird yellow shade to it. I was able to make it look slightly less weird by putting the texture in the emission section, but it still looks quite off. Also, the windows have no transparency. I’m not sure if there’s a way to fix this?
[image: House]

This is the house in cycles, the door looks a little dark, and I’m not 100% sure how to add emission to it as it’s a diffuse shader. Here is what it looks like in eevee, which is more what I’m going for
[image: House 2]

And here’s what it ends up looking like…
[image: House 3]
It's not highlighted because of the selection or anything. At first I thought it might’ve been receiving too much light, as my light is orange in the game, but even if I take the light away completely it looks like this.
Thanks in advance, sorry if this topic is all over the place haha

Comment: Change your bake setting from "combine" to "diffuse". If you're doing a full PBR material, you will have to bake the different maps separately (ex: one for diffuse, one for roughness, one for normal, one for emission, etc...) One of tutorial the videos I always go back to for reference when doing something like this is this one - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9airvjDaVh4

Comment: I watched that video, but here is what it looks like after a diffuse bake.
https://imgur.com/a/jvjEH47
I tried with a transmission bake as well, but it didn't change anything. Also, I don't have any normals, it's all texture, but for some reason the wall texture is not baking properly...

Comment: Is the image on the left the proper one? It looks like it has a noise texture applied as a displacement map. Can you confirm if this is or is not the case?

Comment: Ahh, I forgot haha, I have a voronoi on the displacement

Comment: Then you have to bake a separate displacement map. I think you can use the "roughness" bake setting as it just outputs a black and white (non-color space) image. Just remember to name it right (I've confused myself in the past).

Comment: Oh okay, While my computer is taking forever to bake that, is there any way to get the transmission on the windows working? I tried baking  with transmission, but no luck

Comment: You mean the bake result was empty?

Comment: It baked pure black windows.

Comment: That's strange. I just tested myself. I made a plane and inset it by half so I had basically a square within a square. I gave them each separate materials, both with the same color brick texture, the only difference being that the inner square's material had it's transmission set to 1. I removed any lights from the scene and baked. The result was a black texture with an inner square showing (a slightly darkened) version of the texture. I don't know if it changed anything, but I enabled both "use alpha" and "32 bit float" on my bake image.

Comment: Oh, okay. Well I got a weird thing going on, I totally don't understand this lol. I can't bake it properly anymore, it just turns out like this
https://imgur.com/a/NtbWCFO
I've tried remapping it, switching to a new image, baking it a million different ways...